# is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes (React.js and TypeScript.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create component in react. I am on learning mode. So may be I am doing totally wrong. Below is my code

```
import * as React from 'react'

import styles from './MegaMenu.module.scss'

interface IMenu {
  name: string
  link: string
  subitem?: IMenu[]
}

let menus: IMenu[]
menus = [
  {
    name: "Home",
    link: "#"
  },
  {
    name: "About Us",
    link: "#"
  },
  {
    name: "Products",
    link: "#",
    subitem: [
      {
        name: "SubItem 1",
        link: "#",
        subitem: [
          {
            name: "Sub-SubItem1",
            link: "#"
          },
          {
            name: "Sub-SubItem2",
            link: "#"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "SubItem 2",
        link: "#"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Services",
    link: "#",
    subitem: [
      {
        name: "SubItem 1",
        link: "#"
      },
      {
        name: "SubItem 2",
        link: "#"
      }
    ]
  }
]

class MegaMenu extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.MegaMenu}>
        <div className={styles["menu-container"]}>
          <div className={styles.menu}>
            <MenuList Options={menus} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const MenuList = (Options: IMenu[]) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {
        Options.map((Option: IMenu) => (
          <li key="">
            <a href={Option.link}>{Option.name}</a>
            {/* Base Case */}
            {
              (Option.subitem && Option.subitem.length > 0) &&
              <MenuList Options={Option.subitem} />
            }
          </li>
        ))
      }
    </ul>
  )
}

export default MegaMenu
```

I get below error
[image]

Kindly somebody help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functional components can only have `props` as variable, therefore you have to provide a typing for props and use it like this.

```
interface IMenuListProps {
  options: IMenu[]
}

const MenuList = (props: IMenuListProps) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {
        props.options.map((Option: IMenu) => (
          <li key="">
            <a href={Option.link}>{Option.name}</a>
            {/* Base Case */}
            {
              (Option.subitem && Option.subitem.length > 0) &&
              <MenuList options={Option.subitem} />
            }
          </li>
        ))
      }
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Comment: just curious, would it work with destructuring ?
const MenuList = ({ Options: IMenu[] }) => {

Comment: @FrançoisRichard No that too don't work :( ts error

Comment: @FrançoisRichard Yes you can, but if you're using Typescript you still have to provide a type.Something like this works `const MenuList = ({options}: {options: IMenu[]})`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are declaring a component as **(declare Component with its type Eg: React.FunctionComponent )**

```
export const TestComponent: React.FunctionComponent = () => {}
```

Please note here, you are giving component type here. Now if you pass props to the component you will get **"IntrinsicAttributes"** Error. To solve this you **need to pass the Props Type as well with the Component type** as shown in the below example.

```
// Type of props to pass
export type TestComponentProps = {
    count?: number;
};

//Declare component
export const TestComponent: React.FunctionComponent<TestComponentProps> = 
({count}: TestComponentProps) => {
    console.log("count = ", count)
}

//Use that Component
<TestComponent count={15} />
```